# How do I migrate my current users to aws cognito

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm in the process of migrating my user authentication system to AWS Cognito. I followed this tutorial [here](https://djangostars.com/blog/bootstrap-django-app-with-cognito/) and I can now send the Bearer token to django and it is stored as a user with the username containing the unique sub. The issue I am facing now is, I already have quite a large number of users that are signed up using my previous system, which was a token based authentication method.

My question now is, how do I migrate those users to aws cognito, or is there a way to allow sign-ins using both aws cognito and also the token based authentication.

Also note that, the user model have relationship with other models; so deleting or removing a user will also delete those data tied to a user.

By the way, I am using react and amplify for the frontend authentication.

Comment: In which database are you storing all of your data? And why do you want to switch to Congnito Auth?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? How?